# Replace all links in a file

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

i need some help.
i have a huge php document that contain a lot of links inside it.
I need to replace links with #
for example:

```
Original link: text....<a href="orig-link"> Link text </a> other text .....


How i need it be:  text....<a href="#"> Link text </a> other text .....
```

so i need to change only the link nothing else, the link text etc should stay as it is.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there are no other attributes:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<a href="[^"]+">~', '<a href="#">', $string);
```

Otherwise:

```
$string = preg_replace('~<a ([^>]*)href="[^"]+"([^>]*)>~', '<a \\1href="#"\\2>', $string);
```

Demo:

```
php > $string = 'text....<a asd="blub" href="orig-link" title="bla"> Link text </a> other text .....';
php > echo preg_replace('~<a ([^>]*)href="[^"]+"([^>]*)>~', '<a \\1href="#"\\2>', $string);
text....<a asd="blub" href="#" title="bla"> Link text </a> other text .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$str = 'Original link: text....<a href="orig-link"> Link text </a> other text .....';
$newstr = preg_replace('/(href=.)[^"]+/', '$1#', $str);
echo $newstr;
```

The output is:

```
Original link: text....<a href="#"> Link text </a> other text .....
```